# What is DME Unlock?

Tags: navigation, instrument-procedures

Reading through a NOTAM I found something I don't understand,

```
A0311/17 NOTAMR A2635/16
Q) VTBB/QIDXX/I/NBO/A/000/999/1342N10046E025
A) VTBS  B) 1702080225 C) 1705081100
E) ILS DME I-SES CH38X RWY 01R UNUSABLE BEYOND 15DEG 
LEFT OF LOC COURSE DUE TO DME UNLOCK
```

What is DME Unlock? How does it affect the flight?

Comment: Could you post the NOTAM in full (or at least provide the location identifier)?

Comment: @J.Hougaard added. Now it is very long. The part I am interested in is the last line.

Answer (score 10):

I think it just means a situation in which the DME is "no longer locked on".  Sounds like the DME may not be seen properly from those areas mentioned in the NOTAM.

From the Naval [Instrument Navigation
Workbook](https://www.cnatra.navy.mil/local/docs/pat-pubs/P-403.pdf)

> TACAN Characteristics
>
> 1.Bearing/Distance Unlock. TACAN bearing and distance signals are subject to line-of-sight restrictions because of their utilization of
>   UHF frequencies. Because of the transmission/reception principles,
>   unlock (indicated by rotating of bearing pointer and/or range
>   indicator) will occur if these signals are obstructed.

...

> Aircraft receiver memory circuits prevent unlock for short
>   periods (approximately 10 seconds for DME and 2 seconds for azimuth.) But beyond this unlock
>   occurs and will persist until the obstruction is removed and search cycles are completed. Unlock
>   may occur during maneuvers, such as procedure turns, which cause the aircraft antenna to be
>   obstructed for longer than 2 to 10 seconds